# When coping files from a snow leopard AFP client, timestamps of a few files will change to the current time on the server

Tags: macos, file-sharing

My issue is just what written in the title, but some specifications below...

client: MacOS10.6.7, server: MacOS10.5.8server

- about 20-30 files which has resource forks (this means these files are old data, from like OS9 era)
- mounts a AFP server
- copies files at the Desktop of the client, to the network volume mounted at the client, by drag and drop
- almost of timestamps of copied files are correct(the timestamps they already had) at the server side, but a few of them are wrong(will be the current time file copied).
- files which the timestamps will be changed are not specified but at random.

Anybody has experienced this kind of issue? and managed to resolve?
Any response will be appreciate!

Comment: I can create a file with a resource fork in 1 second on Mac OS X 10.6.7. Just drag&drop some selected text to the desktop. Nothing Mac OS 9 era about it, unfortunately.

Comment: I had not known the way how to make a textClipping file...

Comment: I made 4 files by the way above on MacOS10.6 and copied them to an AFP server, resulting the half of their timestamps changed.. It occurs again, unfortunately. (T_T